# Few doubts regarding 1.constructor and 2.array definition at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, function, constructor

Please help me clear the concepts with following problems: 
(executed and tested on linux,gcc)

Problem 1:

In the following simple example what exactly meant by A a()??

I found that this is not a definition of default constructor but a() is a function with return type is A.

If it is correct then **why this code does not give me any linker error or runtime error**.This code runs and links smoothly as if it knows the definition of function a().

```
class A
{
  public:
     void print()
     {
       printf("In class A\n");
     }
};


int
  main()
  {
    A a();
    //a.fun();  //throws error "request for member ‘fun’ in ‘a’, which is of type ‘A()’"
  }
```

---

problem 2.

In the following code the definition of array b throws error.
 I am not able to find the exact reason for this behavior.

```
int a[]={3,4,21,5,7,86};
 int b[a[3]];     //this throws error why???

 int
  main() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A a();`  This tells the compiler that a function a exists.  Compiler says OK!  But since it's never USED, the linker never check its, and so there's no linker error.

`int a[]={3,4,21,5,7,86};`  Unfortunately, the elements of array are not considered `compile time constants` and thus cannot be used to initialize arrays nor template parameters.  You'll have to set the size of B another way, or do it dynamically at runtime: `int *b = new int[a[3]];`

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

This is known as the [*most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  The following:

```
A a();
```

is a function declaration.  You are not calling that function, so the linker is not obliged to resolve it.  That explains why you don't see any error.

**Problem 2**

The size of an array must be specified with a *constant expression*.  `a[3]` is not a constant expression.

Comment: I wish they had picked a better name, "most vexing parse" sounds so stupid.

Comment: @Seth: I don't think it's formal terminology.  It's just a nickname it's been given by people.

Comment: @Oli: I think it was Scott Meyers who used this phrase first.

Comment: `I found that this is not a definition of default constructor but a() is a function with return type is A.` OP seems aware of what that is.  His question was `why this code does not give me any linker error or runtime error.`

Comment: @Mooing: Well, the reason is because a function declaration is valid C++, I suppose!  Answer is updated, though...

Comment: hmm thank you for your reply but if i define array a as  const to make the values constant ie  const int a[]= { ...} then also it doesn't compile??

Answer (score 0):

```
A a();
```

Its a function declaration with name `a` which takes no argument and returns `A`. Its not a variable declaration.

---

```
int a[]={3,4,21,5,7,86};
int b[a[3]];     //this throws error why???
```

In C++, size of an array should be a const-expression, but `a[3]` is NOT a const expression. Hence the error.

However if you do this:

```
const int a=21;
int b[a];   //okay - now a is const expression.
```

Then its okay.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding problem 2 : c++ doesn't support variable array size